# Can't get my code to correctly sort user input array of numbers (using recursion)

Tags: c++, sorting, recursion

For the life of me I can't get this code to sort correctly. This is a recursion practice, by sorting five numbers that the user inputs, then I display those five numbers from least to greatest. It does most of it correctly, but occasionally it will mess the first or last number up, and switch it with another number in the array. I know the problem is inside the function where is does the swapping, in that second 'if' statement, but I can't figure out how to fix it, I would really appreciate some **direction** as to how to proceed. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

void mySort(int nums[], int first, int size);

int main()
{
    int fiveNumbers[5];
    int firstNum = 0;
    int size = 5;
    cout << "Please enter five numbers, pressing enter after each.\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin >> fiveNumbers[i];
        cout << endl;
    }

    mySort(fiveNumbers, firstNum, size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << fiveNumbers[i] << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void mySort(int nums[], int first, int size)
{
    if (size == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (first < nums[i])
        {
            swap(nums[first], nums[i]);
        }
    }
    first++;
    size--;
    return mySort(nums, first, size);
}
```

Changed my function to reflect the value of the array AT point 'first', instead of the variable 'first' itself. So far it has worked every time!

```
void mySort(int nums[], int first, int size)
{
    if (size == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (nums[first] < nums[i])
        {
            swap(nums[first], nums[i]);
        }
    }
    first++;
    size--;
    return mySort(nums, first, size);
}
```

Comment: You need to [make an urgent appointment to see your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and explain your algorithm to your rubber duck. As is, in your algorithm, the same value `first` is used both as a value to compare "first < nums[i]", and an index in an array "... nums[first]". That makes no logical sense whatsoever. You need your rubber duck's help to straighten out this confusion.

Comment: Ahah! Gotcha. I was using the variable 'first' itself instead of the point of the array AT 'first'. Thanks for helping a beginner out!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Got your code working but forgot the most important part, namely:

You're comparing the index to the array value, use:

```
if (nums[first] < nums[i])
```

Instead of:

```
if (first < nums[i])
```

Also, you always start swapping from the beginning when you should be starting one past `first`.

Instead of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

You want:

```
 for (int i = first + 1; i < 5; i++)
```